# how to link a folder contain .so in java using eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to run a java program **using eclipse in ubuntu**. In my java program ,I linked a java so directly using the absolute path.

The so that I have linked is pointing to the other so present in the lib folder.

I have to access all the so from the lib folder(which contain more than 100 so's)

I have set the `java.library.path` to the lib folder location,but it does not work.

When I check the dependencies of the so which i have linked,the some of the so which are linking is not pointing to the lib folder,it automatically moves to `usr/local/lib`.

When I run the same program in terminal,and use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='path_of_lib_folder`, it works fine in terminal.

But I have to run it in eclipse,it not recognize the lib folder. Pls help me to run the program in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your contribution to the question

**My Intention:**

To link the folder contain the library file(`.so`) in java using eclipse.

**Solution:**

Right click on `src` folder in the eclipse project and select the `Debug As->Debug Configurations...`

Select the `Environment` tab in the Debug Configurations dialogue box.

Click `New` button

Type the `Name` as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the `value` as the folder path (eg,./lib)

Click ok,then Apply

Now the library folder is successfully linked in the java project.

Comment: Pls make use of the above solution

Comment: If you need any help regarding this answer,drop a comment.